# Why does general homogenous solution of differential equations modelling circuits die off after a long time?

Tags: electric-circuits, oscillators, differential-equations, dissipation

I was reading this [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/368195/236654) in Elecronic engineering stack exchange which said that when solving the linear second order differential equation modelling circuits having ac source. We only need to account for particular solution as homogenous part of the differential always dies to zero.

How do we prove mathematically that for all such linear AC circuits the homogenous part of the solution dies to zero at $t\to +\infty$?

Respone to discussion in comments:One of the has comment on this post that it is direct consequence of solution of differential equations. Ok, so for simplicity I assumed a second order differential equation of form:
$$py''+qy' + r = g(t)$$

Now for the homogenous part I do $$ py'' + gy'+r=0$$  , I find that for the solutions of the above equation to die at infinity, I need both roots of the homogenous part of equation to have have negative real part. Now , I know for sure this isn't always mathematically guaranteed, so why so for linear circuits?

Comment: Just solve the DE (as in your link) for the homogeneous case. It will become clear that this solution decays to $0$ for $t \to +\infty$.

Comment: Then I'd have to do case work because there are three cases for second order DE with linear coefficients solution if I am not mistaken @Gert

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the above conclusion holds, regardless of the *characteristic equation* of the DE because the hom. solution always contains exponential term(s).

Comment: But to have the exponential term die off then you need a negative root for charesteric equation (maybe I am wrong here, I am not very familiar with DEs) @Gert

Comment: Look. No one is going to solve this DE for you here, it's too much of a HW&E type question. So look up 'second order linear homog. DEs' and have a little study. It's easy, lemon squeasy.

Comment: I simply asked a property of the differential equation governing circuits not a solution for the differential equation, I told you why I think directly trying to bash it out has it's issues. As per homework-ish questions, I haven't given any premise to start from

Comment: *Deeeep sighgh*. The **solution** to the DE **gives you that property**, that's why we frame problems like that in the form of equations, here a simple DE. We've reached the 'whatever' point in this conversation. Good luck.

Comment: Alright so according to you, all differential equation of form py'' + qy' + r = g(t) has a homogenous part which dies too zero which in essence means the roots of charesteric polynomials will always be negative roots (to get$ y=Ae^{-\lambda t} + Be^{-\lambda' t} $) to die to zero, is that correct? @Gert

Comment: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/introsecondorder.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Physically, the homogeneous solution is a motion that can occur without any driving term. If it were to continue forever, that would be perpetual motion. Every real system has some dissipation, so such motions must decay away when there is no power source. Ultimately it is a consequence of the 2nd law of thermodynamics.

Comment: After you turn that off the driving force you are left with the homogeneous motion. Or, you can forget about the driving term and just start the system off at a non-zero initial condition.

Comment: Hmm I'm looking for a mathematical explanation, however could you give a reference/ elaborate on how this ties in with 2nd law of thermo

Comment: I see what you are asking. If you make an arbitrary network of resistors, capacitors, inductors, and mutual inductors and then compute a transfer function, it will definitely be true that the poles will all be in the left half-plane, so that all homogeneous solutions decay away. So there is a theorem that says if all resistances are positive then the characteristic polynomial is such that all poles are in the left half plane. I’m sorry I can’t give you the details but likely someone else here can.

Comment: Thank you for the keywords, It definitely helps

Comment: You might be interested in this thread: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/374766/why-is-a-linear-passive-circuit-stable-i-e-why-does-its-impulse-response-appro

Comment: There will be other conditions as well: all capacitances and inductances have to be positive. Probably all transformer coupling coefficients have to be < 1.

Comment: I read through the linked post you had sent, it seems to go deep quite fast. I can't follow everything in one go but I'll try rereading it, thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1):

When you apply power to a circuit, there is a transient response (such as when you connect an RC circuit to a battery) followed by a steady-state behavior.  I would assume that the homogeneous part refers to the transients.